# I am getting a strange output in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

This is the error:
unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Matrix1::Matrix1(int,int)" (??0?$Matrix1@H@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main MatrixClass C:\Users\saive\source\repos\MatrixClass\MatrixClass\MatrixClass.obj 1

It tells me that there is something wrong with obj file but I do not know what that is. I am new to c++, and was just trying out a project I found online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit convoluted, I agree. It tells you, that the Constructor `Matrix1::Matrix1(int, int)` is nowhere defined.

Comment: It looks like you are writing a Matrix class. Those are often class templates. Is this the case?

Comment: If `Matrix1` is a template make sure there is no `matrix1.cpp` file and your whole template is implemented in a header or possibly multiple headers : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056)